# How to generate reports for each scenario using Cucumber JVM?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

the default cucumber-html report is generated once the execution is completed, but I want the same report to be generated for each scenario instead.

Is there a direct API that I can use or do I need to write custom formatters to generate the report for each scenario?

Comment: what have you tried until now? how many scenarios do you have? if it is a small number, you can write a different runner class for each scenario, and tag the scenarios. then you can have an html report for each scenario

Comment: Yes, i was able to implement using the Gherkin Formatters successfully;  now its generating report for each scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Gherkin Formatters and pointing to that class instead of format html helped me in generating reports for each scenario.